# Django: unbound method is_authenticated() must be called with AbstractBaseUser instance

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

This issue is rather strange. Here's a stack trace:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost/en/dashboard

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django_mongoengine',
 'django_mongoengine.mongo_auth',
 'django_mongoengine.mongo_admin.sites',
 'django_mongoengine.mongo_admin',
 'django_adyen',
 'spiral_api',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_mongoengine',
 'spiral_admin',
 'rest_framework_docs')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'spiral_api.middlewares.BehalfUserMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'spiral_api.middlewares.AuthHeaderMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  235.                 response = middleware_method(request, response)

File "/code/django_app/spiral_api/middlewares.py" in process_response
  11.     def process_response(self, request, response):

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in inner
  204.             self._setup()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in _setup
  351.         self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()

File "/code/django_app/spiral_api/middlewares.py" in get_user
  18.         user = get_user_middleware(request)

Exception Type: TypeError at /en/dashboard
Exception Value: unbound method is_authenticated() must be called with AbstractBaseUser instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Here's a middleware:

```
from functools import partial

from django.contrib.auth.middleware import get_user as get_user_middleware
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.functional import SimpleLazyObject

from spiral_api.models import SpiralUserProfile


class AuthHeaderMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response['is_login'] = int(request.user.is_active) if hasattr(request, 'user') else 0
        return response


class BehalfUserMiddleware(object):
    def get_user(self, request):
        user = get_user_middleware(request)
        if user.is_authenticated():
            profile = SpiralUserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
            return profile.behalf or user
        else:
            return user

    def process_request(self, request):
        assert hasattr(request, 'session'), (
            "The Django authentication middleware requires session middleware "
            "to be installed. Edit your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting to insert "
            "'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' before "
            "'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'."
        )
        request.user = SimpleLazyObject(partial(self.get_user, request))
        request.behalf = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user_middleware(request))
```

Sadly project is not mine. From exception you see it points to get_user_middleware() function. I've tried to add `print` in there, also as `sys.exit()`, nothing works.. it seems to be it doesn't even come to that function.  Here's how middleware setup looks in Settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'spiral_api.middlewares.BehalfUserMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'spiral_api.middlewares.AuthHeaderMiddleware'
)
```

Also a model `SpiralUserProfile` has a field `behalf` which is reference to model `User`. I'm completely puzzled why exception shows error in a place where interpreter doesn't even come to? How to solve this issue?

Versions of requirements.txt:

```
nose==1.3.7
pinocchio==0.4.2
django_nose==1.4.4
bjoern==1.4.3
amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
apiclient==1.0.3
billiard==3.3.0.23
blinker==1.4
build==1.0.2
celery==3.1.23
Django==1.9.6
django-bootstrap3==7.0.1
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
django-fanout==1.1.1
django-filter==0.13.0
git+https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine
django-redis==4.4.3
django-rest-framework-mongoengine==3.3.0
djangorestframework==3.3.3
drfdocs==0.0.9
EasyProcess==0.2.2
fanout==1.2.0
git+http://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/
gunicorn==19.3.0
httplib2==0.9.2
kombu==3.0.35
mongodbforms==0.3
mongoengine==0.10.6
nltk==3.2.1
oauth2==1.9.0.post1
oauth2client==2.1.0
oauthlib==1.1.2
Pillow==3.2.0
psycopg2==2.6
pubcontrol==2.2.7
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
PyInvoice==0.1.7
PyJWT==1.4.0
pymongo==3.2.2
python-openid==2.2.5
pytz==2016.4
PyVirtualDisplay==0.2
qrcode==5.3
qrplatba==0.3.4
redis==2.10.5
reportlab==3.3.0
requests==2.10.0
requests-oauthlib==0.6.1
rsa==3.4.2
selenium==2.53.2
simplejson==3.8.2
six==1.10.0
uritemplate==0.6
urllib3==1.15.1
xvfbwrapper==0.2.8
zope.dottedname==4.1.0
pyPdf
```

Comment: is this the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how this ever worked, but I can see why you'd get that error. In [django-mongoengine/mongo_auth/models.py](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine/blob/master/django_mongoengine/mongo_auth/models.py) I see this:

```
class BaseUser(object):

    is_anonymous = AbstractBaseUser.is_anonymous
    is_authenticated = AbstractBaseUser.is_authenticated

class User(BaseUser, document.Document):
    ...
```

which seems to be the source of the error.

You can make it work by modifying that library so that the User class implements those methods directly:

```
class User(document.Document):
    ...
    def is_anonymous(self):
        """
        Always returns False. This is a way of comparing User objects to
        anonymous users.
        """
        return False

    def is_authenticated(self):
        """
        Always return True. This is a way to tell if the user has been
        authenticated in templates.
        """
        return True
```

Comment: It seems the django-mongoengine package just accepted a PR that fixes the issue in a different way: https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine/pull/77/files#diff-5a7b5fa78e5ae80551cc405fafe61e5bR45